# Facebook page access token query - body is of type 'String' instead of 'Object'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get Facebook page access_token to use in my automated Microsoft Flow. I follow simple steps as outlined in [this blog post](https://gotoguy.blog/2017/12/17/access-microsoft-graph-api-using-custom-connector-in-powerapps-and-flows/) using GET query `{page name}?fields=access_token` but I keep getting the following error:

> Error details: 'The API operation 'ukaccesstoken' requires the property 'body' to be of type 'Object' but is of type 'String'.'

I have found only [one mention](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Connecting-To-Data/Custom-API-Connector-Trouble/td-p/716187) of similar issue, but I didn't understand the solution as I am very new to this. Please help.

Comment: Nothing on the page you linked to takes about Facebook. It is about how to access Microsoft Graph API. Not Facebook Graph API.

Comment: You are right, my apologies. The right links below: https://medium.com/@fordosa90/a-microsoft-flow-custom-connector-step-by-step-from-scratch-facebook-api-24361ed9bdee https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-blank. I think I figured out what's wrong but still I am unable to fix it: I have 'fields' parameter which is of type 'String' but should be 'Object'; however, there is no 'Object' available in the drop down list of available types. Do you know how can I adjust the query so that it avoids this issue?